# IQKeyboardManager not working for text fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, iqkeyboardmanager

I imported IQKeyboardManger successfully in my login view controller. After that I added this code

//In viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //IQKeyboardManager
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];

    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField:100];

    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:YES];

    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder:YES];

    [self.ad.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

But it's not working in iOS 11.0

Screen 1

[image]

Screen 2

[image]

I added code in app delegate

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

//Identify launching status(Is first time or not)
//If it is first time go to login page
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
    self.lpvc = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LPVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.lpvc;
    NSLog(@"Launched first time");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //IQKeyboarbManager
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
//        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField:100];
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:YES];
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder:YES];
} else {
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedin"]) {
    self.rvc = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RVC"];
    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rvc];
        NSLog(@"Already launched");
        [self getDataFromServer];
 //            [self.rvc checkAppVersion];
    }
}

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return yes;
```

Comment: what s the use of this [self.ad.window makeKeyAndVisible];

Comment: What exactly does not work? What are you expecting?

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik I don't no exactly, I copied from this link.....   http://www.binpress.com/app/iqkeyboardmanager/1869

Comment: @ Glenn I want to move up the screen when we click in side text field

Comment: How did you import to your project? cocoapods or manually?

Comment: I've met this problem, sorted by add 'UIScrollView' to the base view.

Comment: No I directly added to the UIView

Comment: Why are you adding your code in if condition? Just add it before if condition

Comment: @Himanth Yes , I added the code before the if condition, but no use

Comment: Use cocoapods only. You do not have to write any codes for the keyboard manager, it does it all automatically.

Comment: @iPeter I used cocoa pods only. it's imported in AppDelegate successfully, it's worked in previous app, but now in this app it's not working

Comment: Do nothing. remove all the codes related to IQKeyboardManager. and check if it is working or not.

Comment: Which means from cocoa pods also na

Comment: Make sure you are not adding separate done button for keyboard using UIToolBar

Answer (score 0):

Copy that code to `AppDelegate`

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "IQKeyboardManager.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
//ONE LINE OF CODE.
//Enabling keyboard manager(Use this line to enable managing distance between keyboard & textField/textView).
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];

//(Optional)Set Distance between keyboard & textField, Default is 10.
//[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField:15];

//(Optional)Enable autoToolbar behaviour. If It is set to NO. You have to manually create UIToolbar for keyboard. Default is NO.
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:YES];

//(Optional)Setting toolbar behaviour to IQAutoToolbarBySubviews to manage previous/next according to UITextField's hierarchy in it's SuperView. Set it to IQAutoToolbarByTag to manage previous/next according to UITextField's tag property in increasing order. Default is `IQAutoToolbarBySubviews`.
//[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setToolbarManageBehaviour:IQAutoToolbarBySubviews];

//(Optional)Resign textField if touched outside of UITextField/UITextView. Default is NO.
//[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldResignOnTouchOutside:YES];

//(Optional)Giving permission to modify TextView's frame. Default is NO.
//[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setCanAdjustTextView:YES];

//(Optional)Show TextField placeholder texts on autoToolbar. Default is NO.
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder:YES];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
 }
```

and it will work fine.

Note : Make sure you have update to latest version (5.0.3)

Comment: Yes I added yesterday through pods,

Comment: My code in AppDelegate is self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil]; //Identify launching status(Is first time or not)//If it is first time go to login page

Comment: Can you change the value 10 or remove setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField line and check again?

Comment: if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"]) {
        self.lpvc = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LPVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.lpvc;
        NSLog(@"Launched first time");
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

Comment: //IQKeyboarbManager
        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField:100];
        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:YES];
        [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setShouldShowTextFieldPlaceholder:YES];
    }

Comment: else {
        if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"loggedin"]) {
        self.rvc = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RVC"];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.rvc];
            NSLog(@"Already launched");
        }
    }
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

Comment: I removed setKeyboardDistanceFromTextField , but it's not working